# How to insert sequence number into SQL Server from Oracle

Tags: sql-server, oracle

I would like to ask on how to insert sequence number from Oracle into SQL Server. Thanks.

When I execute this insert, an error is shown:

> ORA-02069: global_names parameter must be set to TRUE for this operation.

Code:

```
INSERT INTO COMPLETE_DOCK@mssql ("ATDI_ORD_NO", "ATDI_Q_NO", "ATDI_Vehicle")
VALUES ('QQ/123/ABC', queue_no_seq.NEXTVAL, 'ABC1234');
```

Comment: sorry guys, that is typo.

Comment: even i have set global_names = true.. The error still there

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO COMPLETE_DOCK@mssql ("ATDI_ORD_NO", "ATDI_Q_NO", "ATDI_Vehicle")
VALUES ('QQ/123/ABC', queue_no_seq.NEXTVAL, 'ABC1234');
```